# Recover an $L^1$ integrand by partial differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lebesgue-measure

Denote by $m$ the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f$ be an element of $L^1(m)$ that takes only nonnegative values. Define $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by
$$F(x,y) = \int\limits _{(-\infty,x] \times (-\infty,y]} fdm.$$ Is there a counterexample to the statement that $\partial _2\partial _1F = f$ a.e.? Or this is actually a true statement?

I can establish with the Fubini-Tonelli theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus that

(i) there is an $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of measure $0$ such that $(\partial _1F)(x,y)$ exists for all $(x,y) \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \times \mathbb{R}$, and

(ii) for every $x \in A$, there is a $B_x \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of measure 0 such that $(\partial _2\partial _1F)(x,y)$ exists for all $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus B_x$.

However, I have no idea on how to prove that $\displaystyle\bigcup\limits _{x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A} \{x\} \times B_x$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of measure $0$.

Comment: Did you try to use Lebesgue's differentiation theorem?

Comment: I think Theorem 3.1, implication (2) => (3), here proves this: https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2010/154/sremr.pdf

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Have tried it before. But it seems not working well because at least one partial differentiation involves integration over a set that does not satisfies the assumption of Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you! I'll check the paper. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1 in Serrin J. (1961), On the Differentiability of Functions of Several Real Variables. *Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis*, 7, 359–372.

Comment: It would help if you added just a bit more information, such as: what question does Lemma 1 answer? What does it say, and how is it related to your question?